# How to combine lines from separate text files into one new text tile using Shell Script

Tags: bash, list, shell, paste

I just want to preface this by saying I am an absolute noob to shell script, so stick with me here.

Essentially, I am trying to combine lines of text from separate test files (one line from HC_01_MNoFraming.txt added at the end of the corresponding line from HC_01_Gist.txt) into a single line of text on a newly created text file called HC_01_MGNoFraming.txt. This combination of the lines of text would occur for each of the four lines of text in each text file. Below is an example:

HC_01_Gist.txt

```
12.0130754383 33.0026698754 117.01282238700001 182.01823507400002 201.005570202 220.010026843 352.023495725 478.012859369 518.0072172580001 
12.012680624100001 56.0118834624 144.026174161 167.018345335 228.002317522 247.00666698400002 356.027611312 434.014129075 478.013307259 
56.01133045 142.00709709999998 207.0121417 331.01635039999996 350.0040858 369.0084907 390.01512310000004 409.0028586 430.0265601 512.0175128999999 556.0159299 
12.012615221199999 176.01120546400003 199.00347731 243.019245908 430.00998814900004 472.02324678400004 495.01541966900004
```

HC_01_MNoFraming

```
262.006565969 283.013202477 375.015624781 541.016055549 
33.019710919299996 497.017719727 537.0287543219999 
121.0167582 226.0165682 
75.01583263170001 113.024949998 262.023691934 386.010783941 537.011983108
```

HC_01_MGNoFraming.txt

```
12.0130754383 33.0026698754 117.01282238700001 182.01823507400002 201.005570202 220.010026843 352.023495725 478.012859369 518.0072172580001 262.006565969 283.013202477 375.015624781 541.016055549 
12.012680624100001 56.0118834624 144.026174161 167.018345335 228.002317522 247.00666698400002 356.027611312 434.014129075 478.013307259 33.019710919299996 497.017719727 537.0287543219999 
56.01133045 142.00709709999998 207.0121417 331.01635039999996 350.0040858 369.0084907 390.01512310000004 409.0028586 430.0265601 512.0175128999999 556.0159299 121.0167582 226.0165682 
12.012615221199999 176.01120546400003 199.00347731 243.019245908 430.00998814900004 472.02324678400004 495.01541966900004 75.01583263170001 113.024949998 262.023691934 386.010783941 537.011983108
```

I tried several things but the simplest solution I could find online was just using the paste command like this:

```
#(A) First Timing File = Timing File you Want to Be in Front 

A=HC_01_Gist.txt

#(B) Second Timing File Timing File you Want to Be in Back 

B=HC_01_MNoFraming.txt

#(C) Output Timing File Name C=HC_01_MGNoFraming.txt

#------------------------------------------------------------ 
paste $B $A
paste $B $A >$C
```

Looking at the terminal output, this is what this code gives:

```
262.006512.0130754383 33.0026698754 117.01282238700001 182.01823507400002 201.005570202 220.010026843 352.023495725 478.012859369 518.0072172580001 
33.0197112.012680624100001 56.0118834624 144.026174161 167.018345335 228.002317522 247.00666698400002 356.027611312 434.014129075 478.013307259 
121.016756.01133045 142.00709709999998 207.0121417 331.01635039999996 350.0040858 369.0084907 390.01512310000004 409.0028586 430.0265601 512.0175128999999 556.0159299 
75.0158312.012615221199999 176.01120546400003 199.00347731 243.019245908 430.00998814900004 472.02324678400004 495.01541966900004
```

It almost looks like in terminal that the paste command starts working but then after the first data point of HC_01_MNoFraming, the paste jumbles up the text and then resumes with the second data point of HC_01_Gist.txt.

Looking at the HC_01_MGNoFraming.txt file that the code creates:

```
262.006565969 283.013202477 375.015624781 541.016055549 
    12.0130754383 33.0026698754 117.01282238700001 182.01823507400002 201.005570202 220.010026843 352.023495725 478.012859369 518.0072172580001 
33.019710919299996 497.017719727 537.0287543219999 
    12.012680624100001 56.0118834624 144.026174161 167.018345335 228.002317522 247.00666698400002 356.027611312 434.014129075 478.013307259 
121.0167582 226.0165682 
    56.01133045 142.00709709999998 207.0121417 331.01635039999996 350.0040858 369.0084907 390.01512310000004 409.0028586 430.0265601 512.0175128999999 556.0159299 
75.01583263170001 113.024949998 262.023691934 386.010783941 537.011983108 
    12.012615221199999 176.01120546400003 199.00347731 243.019245908 430.00998814900004 472.02324678400004 495.01541966900004
```

I'm wondering about two things:
1)How can I fix the output .txt file to have the data points in-line 2) how can I ensure that the data points for HC_01_Gist.txt go before the data points for HC_01_MNoFraming.

Thanks and I'd be more than happy to clarify my problem and answer any questions you have.

Comment: You can do it with `paste` https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html

Comment: Hey @Fravadona, I did try using paste but the output text file had the formatting all messed up. Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: `paste` will concatenate the lines using a Tab as delimiter but you can change it with the `-d` option

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).